# Find roadblocks on Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

In my application I have used `Google Map` SDK. I have two addresses source and destination and I have showed path between these addresses. It is work perfectly.

So my question is I want know, which road is blocked ? so need to show other path or alternatives route. I am using Google direction APIs for getting routes. I know Google direction APIs give `alternatives=true` but it can not helped. I will give you source and destination address which have road blocked.

**Source address : Blue Nile Bridge, Khartoum, Sudan**

**Destination address : Nile St, Khartoum, Sudan**

Comment: When you say roadblocks do you mean roads that were closed temporarily/permanently or do you refer to traffic congestion?

Comment: Yes i mean roads that were closed temporarily/permanently

Comment: Road closures are controlled by Google in their data. They won't suggest route for road segments marked as closed. If you would like to let Google know that some road segment is closed just follow this document: https://www.localguidesconnect.com/t5/News-Updates/Exclusive-Edit-a-road-segment-in-Google-Maps/ba-p/149865